# Matlab: Image stitching and blending

Tags: image, matlab, blend, image-stitching

Hey guys. I got two images from video frames. They have a certain portion of overlap. After warping one of them, I'm currently trying to blend them together. In other words, I would like to stitch them together. But I don't know how to accomplish that. Can anybody please give me some help? Thank you!

Let's say the image data is store in 'image1_warped' and 'image2'. Appreciated your help!

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590220/aligning-multiple-images-into-one-image

Comment: Yes you are right. The answer there is helpful. Thank you mor22!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword here is [Image Registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration). The [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f20-9579.html) provides some functions for this purpose. The documentation has a some of demos as [examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f12-23518.html).

Comment: Thank you Amro! I'm playing around with the functions under the toolbox you recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the blog post: [Blend images with MATLAB](http://imageprocessingblog.com/blend-images-with-matlab/),
with nice examples, and the MATLAB code.

Answer (score -1):

Where the two images join apply the Photoshop clone tool (vary the percentage of opacity and size as required)